# How do I change the Django default test database?

Tags: mysql, django

The production database is named:

```
project_db
```

The default test db is:

```
test_project_db
```

My production server provider requires the database name start with the account name.
So I could go with:

```
projects_db_test
```

or some variant.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [TEST_NAME](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-TEST_NAME) setting.